# Difference in socket syntax

Tags: python

I'm having some trouble understanding the variant syntax format when creating sockets (I've started learning Python a few weeks ago).

Can someone please explain what is the difference (if any) between the below?

1. s = socket()
2. s = socket.socket()
3. s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

Thanks.

Comment: The answer depends on what imports you used. 1 and 2 are the same if they are from the same import

Comment: yes you're right...I totally forgot about the differences of how you import modules. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The diffrence depend on what module you use.
If you use `from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM` :

1. This will work. s will be uninitialized socket object.
2. Will not work, because socket is constructor and not a module.
3. This will work. s will be initialized socket object.

If you use `import socket` :

1. Will not work, because socket is module and not a constructor(not a function- you cant call it).
2. This will work. s will be uninitialized socket object.
3. Will not work, because socket is module and not a constructor.

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

For #3, you might need to modify your code as follows:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```

Reference:
https://www.py4e.com/code3/socket1.py

Thanks